# How does ASP.NET MVC routing work (at a low level)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've done my fair share of Googling "How does ASP.NET MVC routing work" and so forth. Yes, I already know that you can make the URL address hook up to the Controller and Action names and blah blah blah. But I wan't to understand how that happens. **None of the articles I can find describe how an ASP.NET MVC application gets the names of classes/methods within the program itself.**

The reason it seems strange to me is because C# is a compiled language and therefore the names of classes, variables, etc., don't have any meaning after compile time. Unless the compilation of the program has some way of essentially reading it's own source code.

By the way, I've read [C# In Depth](https://www.manning.com/books/c-sharp-in-depth-third-edition), so feel free to give me in-depth, Skeet-certified answers. :)

It would also help if you could show me where in [this ASP.NET MVC application of mine](https://github.com/jamkin/Snake/tree/master/SnakeGame) the file is that performs the magic I'm confused about.

I am not the type of developer who feels comfortable writing code if he doesn't understand what happens behind the scenes.

Comment: Yes, applications can have knowledge about themselves. It's called "reflection". See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx)

Comment: The part that handles all the details of locating your controllers and instantiating them is done by Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc, an assembly it's referencing. You are free to look at the source code for that, it's on GitHub. And by the way, you have to feel comfortable working on top of layers you don't understand. That will always be the case unless you're a physicist, and even then they'll tell you there's a lot we don't know. So know the level you work primarily in, and know a little about the layer below it and you'll be fine.

Comment: [mvc pipeline architecture](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mvc%20pipeline%20architecture)

Comment: As it stands, this question is too broad for SO. It is not possible to tell what specific information you are after (other than possibly generalizing to "Reflection"). If you want to understand how .NET routing works, I suggest you study the source code for `System.Web.Routing.Route`, but it is more than can be explained in this format. Also, you didn't specify which version of MVC you are using - MVC 6 has big routing changes.